# How do I make PHPStorm think my file is in a different directory for Intellisense/completion?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, phpstorm, organization

I am using Laravel (PHP Framework) for my website. In Laravel, code organization is (loosely) as follows

```
/app
    /views
        [my base file A].php
        [my base file B].php
        [my base file C].php
/public
    /css
    /js
    /lib
    index.php
```

There are actually many folders in `/app` but I only showed the important one I'll be adding to: `/views`.
Because of how Laravel organizes things, the `public/index.php` file is used as the main loaded view of the application - but it loads the actual html from one of the `views/[my base file].php` files.

So `[my base file A].php` would look like this, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Normalize.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/out.css" type="text/css" />
```

where the folder is `css/` because this markup will eventually go into `public/index.php`. I get errors because in this file at `app/views/` there is no `css/` folder.

I fear that as I fill these files with a lot of code and references to things in the `public/` folder, I'll get way too many errors for my liking. My example is just `<link>` now but I'll have much more than that. I also need the completion - I'll be using direct AngularJS bindings from $scope, as in `<h3> {{messages.hello}} </h3>` (meaning I'll access a variable in a javascript file and I need the completion to make life easier).

**So my question is:** What I'd like to do is still have all the completion / intellisense / error reporting done on the files in `/views` **like the file was in the `/public` folder** and already a part of `index.php` ... Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Currently I'm thinking something along the lines of moving my code out of the folder, but
- It may be bad practice to move these things into a folder designated as public
- It may mess up Laravel

Comment: some help perhaps in this video. Is for webStorm but concepts are same in phpstorm  http://go.jetbrains.com/426QVD1140001sB00u0SV00

Comment: Mark `public` folder as **Resource Root**

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne! Post as an answer and I'll give you the check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to mark `public` folder as **Resource Root**.